# How to catch all newly created objects of type or subtype Widget with AspectJ?

Tags: java, aspectj

In order to get all newly instantiated widgets I tried the following code

```
after(final Widget widget) : execution (* Widget+.new(..)) && this(widget) {
    ...
}
```

but it fails hard every time there are chained constructors (several constructors in the same class, mutually referring).

I'm in need of collecting all the kinds of widgets that are created in an application. I can't use `call` instead of `execution` because that would mean the woven code would become part of the calling code, and not of the `Widget` code, which is troublesome as there are lots of libraries involved in this project, and that would make me have to weave all of them in order to accomplish the described endeavor.

Thanks

### Edit (more info)

Consider the following class:

```
class A {
  private int i;

  public A(int i) {
    this.i = i;
    initialize();
  }

  public A() {
    this(0);
  }
}

after(final A a) : execution (* A+.new(..)) && this(a) {
  ...
}

//test
new A(0); //caught by the aspect and fine
new A(); //caught by the aspect twice, once for every constructor.
```

The situation gets even worse if you consider an hierarchy of `A`s:

```
class B extends A {
  public B() {
    super();
  }

  public B(int i) {
    super(i);
  }
}

//test
new B(0); //caught by the aspect twice, once as B and once as A
new A(); //caught by the aspect thrice, once for B and twice for A
```

I'd like to only catch the object once, and only after the object is totally constructed (that is, it has run the "outer" constructor to the end), being the aspect code injected into the class under consideration and not outside it (so a `call` wouldn't be acceptable).

There's an interesting discussion I found the other about this topic on the AspectJ mailing lists: http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/aspectj-users/msg09651.html. It describes a possible (non-complete if I am not wrong) solution, involving some sort of stack analysis.

### Edit2

This simply hack seems to do the trick:

```
after(A a) : initialization(A+.new(..)) && this(a) {
    if (a.getClass() == thisJoinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringType())
                //fully constructed object caught
}
```

Comment: I think I know what you mean, but just to be sure, can you please elaborate with a more extensive code sample which is actually compileable and reproduces your actual error? Just "failing hard" seems to be a too vague description.

Comment: i'll do it tomorrow. from what i've been thinking about, what i'm asking is not easily done and may involve hackery. good night

Comment: Then it is good that I asked because from what I understood it would be pretty easy. Give it a try, I think I can help.

Comment: My AspectJ is a bit rusty, but can't you catch that with something like `&& !cflowbelow(widget.new)`?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you should be able to use the initialization pointcut.  See the [AspectJ docs](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/quick.html) for more info on that pointcut.  Essentially, you should do something like this:

```
after(final A a) : initialization (* A+.new(..)) && this(a) {
  ...
}
```

The nice thing here is that you can be tricky and specify a specific constructor. In the following case, only the 1-arg constructor is matched.  0-arg constrcutor is not.

```
initialization (* A+.new(int))
```

Comment: This won't work for arbitrary subclasses, as stated in the OP. What I'm looking for is to get any already fully-initialized object of a given class-hierarchy. Your solutions, as given, will give me at best both fully-initialized and still-not-fully-initialized objects. See the B example above, your solution will catch both B constructors and A constructors separately, and I'd like to only get B's.

Comment: Is it that you only want the pointcut to match a single time per cflow, or that you want to *only* match on `B`?  If the former, then you should use the cflowbelow pointcut (I'll edit answer above), if the latter, just change `A+` to `B`.

Comment: I want to catch any new fully-initialized object. If to initialize object X it has to go through 5 constructors, I don't care about any one of them particularly. I just want the full object.

Comment: Right...I forgot that cflowbelow wouldn't work in this situation (just re-read that mailing list thread).  A bit annoying.  Also, be careful of your hack from the second edit.  This will match twice if you have a this() call inside of a constructor.  I'm afraid that the stack trace hack is the only solution I can think of.

Comment: From preliminary tests I made yesterday, that doesn't seem to be a problem. It seems AspectJ does its work well for this() calls, it just won't look for super() calls.